# Maya Python Playback Create object each time a frame is played

Tags: python, events, playback, maya

Update :)
I have a UI with 2 buttons that control playback, "play" and "stop". 
I defined a CustomLocator object. When the playback is running after pressing Start button, I would like to create and draw a customLocator ***each time a frame is played***. Right now the locator is drawn when pressing the start button. But it's not drawn each time a frame is played and I can' t figure how to do it...thanks for your help

```html
class PlayBackDoSomething():
    def __init__(self):
        self.drawUI()
        self.state = False
        
    
    def drawUI(self):
        if pm.window("UI_MainWindow", exists = True):
            pm.deleteUI("UI_MainWindow")
         
        pm.window("UI_MainWindow", title = "test playback...", w = 150, h = 150, mnb = False, mxb = False, sizeable = True)
        pm.columnLayout("UI_MainLayout", w = 150, h =300)
        pm.button("UI_pbStartButton", label = "Start", w = 150, command=self.pbStart)
        pm.button("UI_pbStopButton", label = "Stop", w = 150, command=self.pbStop)  
        pm.showWindow("UI_MainWindow") 

    def pbStart(self,*args):
        pm.play(state=True)
        self.state = True
        self.doTheJob()        
                            
    def pbStop(self,*args):
        pm.play(state=False)
        self.state = False
        self.stopTheJob()
         
    def doTheJob(self):
        #this is basically part of code that i want to execute each time a frame is updated after pressing Play button
        print ("start of job")
        a = pm.keyframe(query = True, timeChange = True) 
        print a
        
        t =  pm.currentTime()
        cl = CustomLocator(t, 0,0)
        cl.draw()
        
               
    def stopTheJob(self):
        print ("end of job")

    
class CustomLocator():
    def __init__(self, x, y, z):
        self.x = x   
        self.y = y 
        self.z = z 
        
    def draw(self):
        pm.spaceLocator( p=(self.x, self.y, self.z) )
        pm.spaceLocator( p=(self.x, self.y, self.z-5) )
        pm.spaceLocator( p=(self.x, self.y, self.z+5) )
        
            
      
def main():
    pb = PlayBackDoSomething()


main()
```

Answer (score 0):

You can call your print by putting

```
print (time);
```

into an expression on an object in your scene.  I'd only do this for debugging, since prints will slow down the interactive performance of the scene while you're working on it. If needed, you can add the expression to something like a camera when the start button is pushed and then remove it when you're done

**update**

You can do the same thing for creating locators (again, I recommend dynamically creating and removing the expression when playback stops or is complete. Here's a dumb example that creates locators as a cube moves around on playback

```
pCube1.translateX = sin(time);
float $tx = pCube1.translateX;
float $ty = pCube1.translateY;
float $tz = pCube1.translateZ;
spaceLocator -p $tx $ty $tz;
```

You could also just force update the time using `cmds.currentTime()` and do your process for every frame. That's much easier for traditional programming tasks than shoehorning this into an expression.

Comment: thanks for your help, as my code was a bit confused about what I really expected to do, I just updated my post

Comment: expression editor is very  slow with python object so  I prefer to not consider that option. Force the update of time using cmds.currentTime() is not bad.. I can start a loop and iterate cmds.currentTime(i+=1) with my Start button but I don't know how to break it with the stop button...

Comment: The only way to interupt a process like that would be to use the main progress bar, set it to interrutable and let the user stop it from there.   UI elements you create by hand won't be live during script execution.